# Magento can't recognize memcached php sessions

Tags: php, session, magento, memcached

I'm working on a magento deployment with a main-aim at **streamlining product creation**. 
Basically we have some very time-consuming calls in the back-end, which should run asynchronous so the user can work on.

- My first shot at this was using `AJAX` to post the data to the time-consuming script and relocate the user through `javascript`.

This somewhat works but the magento sessions seem to be dependant on the php sessions - as far as I can see a user will have a session created in the directory specified in `php.ini` and one created in `magento/var/session`.

Since this php session is file based I wont be able to get any response from the server in the second request (the redirection) or any other requests within the same session before the first call (the script called by `ajax`) has finished.

- My solution to this was to memcache these session files (alongside magento) in order to allow these asynchronous calls.

However, magento can't seem recognize these sessions now that they are stored in memcache.

Why is this?

I would think that it used the standard php functions when accessing these sessions - I can't find any of these functions in the source code though, but they must be called in some way.

I have successfully tested that the sessions can be stored and loaded properly.
I get no error messages and the log is empty.

Any ideas why magento can't handle this?

Is it even an acceptable approach in order to achieve these asynchronous calls, or is there a much better solution?

**TL;DR**
Standard php sessions are being stored using memcache. Magento can't seem to recognize them. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have memcached defined in your `app/etc/local.xml` file.  It should look something like this:

```
<session_save><![CDATA[memcache]]></session_save>
<session_save_path><![CDATA[tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10]]></session_save_path>
```

Replace `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` with your memcached server address.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This, however, isn't quite the case. I have this exact code in my local.xml file which makes magento's own sessions memcached - and this does work. For instance, I can have mangento's own sessions memcached and php's sessions saved as files - this works. The problem occurs when I memcache the php sessions. Basically there's two different sessions per session (makes any sense?)
With a file structure it could look something like this:
/web/tmp/[php sessions, path described in php.ini]
/web/www/magento/temp/sessions/[magento sessions, path in config.xml]

Comment: FTR I'm testing this in wamp.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. You should reuse magento session in your custom php script which you invoke by ajax.

Answer (score 0):

So this is awkward.. Needless to say when I tested it this morning  having rebooted it worked. Perhaps the memcache service had to be restarted? Didn't solve my original issue about asynchronous calls as I had hoped for, but that is another story. :D 
Good day